# std::function as a std::map key

Tags: c++, std-function

I want to insert std::function as a std::map key, but the code doesnt compile, any thoughts?

```
int sum(int a, float b){
    return a+b;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<int(int, float)>f = sum;
    std::map <std::function<int(int, float)>, std::string> mapa;
    mapa.insert(std::make_pair(f, "sum"));
}
```

Comment: but the code doesnt compile - what does it do if it doesn't compile? Any error?

Comment: could it be that you want string to be the key and function to be the value?

Comment: This is very unusual. Can you describe what you want the program to do? We may be able to offer  alternatives.

Comment: [yx problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Could it be that you want a `std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int,float)>` ? So that you can look up the function by its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map` requires ordered keys.

`std::function` does not support an order.

They can't work together.

Adding ordering requirements to a `std::function` isn't trivial.  I'd advise against trying.

Note that the reversed map has no problems.

`std::function` doesn't even support `==`, let alone `<` or (for the unordered map) `std::hash`.

Reconsider your design.